# In nifi how to Fetch Access Token and clientid

Tags: apache-nifi

In linux I have started nifi without any authentication for getting  Access Token and clientid from nifi rest api.[image]

```
Access tokens are only issued over HTTPS.
```

So, how can I get the access token, how to enable https in nifi.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a lot of posts and documentation on how to secure your NiFi instance...

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/administration-guide.html#security_configuration

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/886/securing-nifi-step-by-step.html

https://pierrevillard.com/2016/11/29/apache-nifi-1-1-0-secured-cluster-setup/